# Setting custom local storage Path in QML

Tags: sqlite, path, qml, storage, local

I m trying to put a custom path in QML file but can't get it done.

I'm trying to get de db in a shared folder where i'm willing to put the DB so any person who has the program can acces to data.

I'm using Sqlite and Qt Creator 5.7 but not a lot of info about this.

Comment: You can set the path with [QQmlEngine::setOfflineStoragePath](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qqmlengine.html#offlineStoragePath-prop)

Answer (score 1):

You can simply COPY the database from its default path.  Typically that is located (In windows anyways)  at

`C:\Users\<username>AppData\Local\<program name>\QML\OfflineStorage\Databases`

and on Mobile devices it is stored in a similar place --

on android its in a sub folder of:

`/data/data/<Program Name>`

On *nix it is located:

`/home/<user>/.local/share/[ProjectName]/QML/OfflineStorage/Databases`